# Firestore What should I set the user's document id to?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I noticed that when creating a new document(new user) in Cloud Firestore, Firestore will randomly assign an id. Should I instead set this Document to the manually generated User UID? If not, how do I reference the randomly generated Firestore Document Id when updating the fields in said document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single correct answer here, but most apps use the UID of the user as the document ID for that user's profile in a `users` collection.

One reason for this is that it allows a direct lookup of the user's profile document based on their UID, which is typically the most common way of identifying a user in an app.

Using the UID as the document ID also ensures that you can only have a single profile document per UID, which is a common requirement.

Comment: there are other ways?
 the only answer is a user profile based on the users UID, there are no other methods without making it pointless and redundent

Comment: In my experience it depends on what (if anything) needs to be unique in the context. So often it is UID, but I also see username, email address, or other values. If you have another experience, I'd recommend posting that as another answer, as it could be valuable to OP.